# How to replace the diff output shown by magit?

Tags: magit, diff

Is there a way to switch out magit's diff display with a 3rd party output?

I would like to use [delta](https://github.com/dandavison/delta) which has syntax highlighting & word-level diffs.

Is there a way of integrating 3rd party packages? Or would I be better off writing my own package that launches a different kind of diff view from magit?

[image]

This is a comparison with vdiff & delta.
[image]

---

Note: I'm awaer of ediff, however it doesn't seem to have a way to produce a small/concise summary of the diff (the whole buffer is shown and each file needs to be handled one-by-one).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: `(setq magit-diff-refine-hunk 'all)` gets you that nice word-level highlighting in magit diffs. Delta looks awesome though, I'll have to check that out!

Answer (score 1):

There is a package [magit-delta](https://melpa.org/#/magit-delta) that does exactly this.

Comment: Unfortunately this packages only colors magit's diff, it doesn't support a side-by-side diff.